# How to store MySQL data in .JSON file format?

Tags: php, mysql, json

The thing which I want to do is, to fetch a data (phone number) from MySQL, and store it in an array, which is defined in a file format .JSON!

I don't know any JSON so I am having this trouble. 
A function uses administrators.json file to get phone numbers, which is actually written in a array, like this:

```
[
  {
    "phone_number": "+1555555555",
    "name": "Foo"
  }
]
```

But I don't want static values, I want to retrieve phone number from MySQL, and then pass that number to this JSON array. 
How am I suppose to do that?

The function that uses this administrators.json is as follows:

```
 private function _notificationRecipients()
    {
        $adminsFile = base_path() .
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
            'config' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
            'administrators.json';
        try {
            $adminsFileContents = \File::get($adminsFile);

            return json_decode($adminsFileContents);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException $e) {
            Log::error(
                'Could not find ' .
                $adminsFile .
                ' to notify admins through SMS'
            );
            return [];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function on php called **json_encode** which basically does the work for you. You can then write the result to a file.

Comment: but the file is having .json format! Can I run php code in it? Will I have to change the .json to .php?

Comment: I thought you just wanted to create a JSON from the data retrieved from the database? Or am I getting things wrong.

Comment: @ThesK you don't run code in the json file, you read/write the json file with PHP.  json_encode converts a PHP array to a JSON string.  json_decode converts a JSON string to a PHP array.

Comment: @DebetWah Yes, but for retrieving the data(phone number) I will need to run the query right!? Where I am suppose to write this query? in the notificationRecipients function?

Comment: you could do it in any php script. You just wanted to generate the JSON file right?

Comment: @Devon yes! I understood your point, but i am not used to json that much. What should I do to the array? should I keep it empty? Cause every user in database will have different numbers.

Comment: isn't the array your storage for numbers of all users? why would you need to empty them for every user?